# How to use more than one MySQL master server in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking for a best solution that suits my requirements. I would like to use MySQL with a lot of instances, so I need to be able to add as much master servers with slaves servers as might be needed in the future. There also will be sharding. Currently I've found out that GCP doesn't allow you to add more than one master server to a running instance. If so, what can I do then? I need to create 3 or more master servers and add slave servers to them. And if there is a new row in one of the master servers, the 3 slaves will receive that row and everything will by synchronized, so I'll be able to do a simple `SELECT` query in one of these slaves to get the actual data. I'm sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for it's called [read replica](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/). Using [Google Cloud Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart) will let you implement a setup like the one you are describing, [deploying multiples read replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica) really fast

For the sharding part, you just need to deploy multiple masters with its own read replicas and on your application logic implement the needed code to find the data in the right instance.